# Switching between div's with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, switch-statement

I have two div boxes `promo1` and `promo2`. `promo1` is displayed whereas `promo2` is hidden. Every x seconds I would like to switch the boxes so it hides `promo1` and fades in `promo2` and vice versa.

Parden my scripting skills, I'm still learning lol.
This is what I got so far..

```
function switch1(){
      $("#promo1").hide("fast");
      $("#promo2").fadeIn("slow");
}
function switch2(){
      $("#promo2").hide("fast");
      $("#promo1").fadeIn("slow");
}
$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval( "switch1()", 5000 );
setInterval( "switch2()", 10000 );

});
```

Now the problem with this as you can see is the `switch2` overlaps with `switch1`. Is there a simpler way to do what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: Are the divs on top of each other? Becaues then you'd only have to fade the top one in and out

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, the greater community of Developers online. Excellent first question!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.toggle();`

```
function switch1(){
      $("#promo1").toggle('slow');
     $("#promo2").toggle('slow');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#promo2").hide();
setInterval(switch1, 5000 );


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/X6G9Y/

Comment: I really like this method, the transition effect is a lot cooler lol, Thanks for your help mate!

Answer (score 1):

**Don't Re-Invent the Wheel**

Unless you're trying to teach yourself jQuery, the best solution would be to go with something more sure, like the Cycle plugin for jQuery: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

**Unless you *really* want to...**

If you'd like to roll a custom solution, the following may help. Note also that the following will work with any number of promo divs, unlike some of the other answers provided. Granted, you only mentioned two but you shouldn't paint yourself into a corner:

```
/* Hide all but first promo div */
$("div[id^=promo]:gt(0)").hide();

/* Setup Interval */
setInterval(function(){
  /* Hide visible div, get reference to next promo div */
  reference = $("div:visible").hide().next("div[id^=promo]");
  /* If there is not a next promo div, show the first promo div */
  reference.length ? $(reference).fadeIn() : $("div:first").fadeIn() ;
  /* Do this every five seconds */
}, 5000);
```

Demo online: http://jsbin.com/ewusu5/edit

Be sure to either perform this logic at the end of your document, or within a ready-safe method like the following:

```
$(function(){
  /* code to be ran when document is ready */
});
```

Comment: I knew there were a few ready made scripts out there but I wanted to try and have a go myself

Comment: @Ian I understand the desire to be creative - I had the same feeling when answering your question. I wanted to see if I could create the same effect easily enough but expansive enough to accommodate any number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to switch between states:

```
var current_promo = 1;
function switch_promo(){
    if (current_promo == 1) {
        $("#promo1").hide();
        $("#promo2").fadeIn("slow");
        current_promo = 2;
    } else {
        $("#promo2").hide();
        $("#promo1").fadeIn("slow");
        current_promo = 1;
    }
}
setInterval(switch_promo, 1000);
```

I removed the "fast" parameter on `hide` because otherwise the 2 elements are displayed at the same time and unless they're positioned precisely (or you chain the effects), it's ugly.

Comment: @Ian While this solution may be sufficient, it limits you to only two promo divs which may be painting yourself into a corner if you wish to have three or four in the future.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes I did wonder about that, but it does exactly as I need for now. I only wish to switch from two boxes

Answer (score 0):

I expanded what was already shown and added a indicator feature that can be used and placed anywhere. http://jsfiddle.net/BadBoyBill/8yHmy/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div[id^=marquee]:gt(0)").hide();

    function startTimer(){
        i = setInterval(rotate, 2000);
        return i;
    }

    var intID = startTimer();

    function stopTimer(){
        clearInterval(intID);
    }

    function rotate(){
        reference = $("div[id^=marquee]:visible").hide().next("div[id^=marquee]");
        reference.length ? $(reference).fadeIn() : $("div[id^=marquee]:first").fadeIn() ;
        dot = $(".indicator-on[id^=indicator]").removeClass("indicator-on").next("a[id^=indicator]").addClass("indicator-on");
        dot.length ? $(dot).addClass("indicator-on") : $("a[id^=indicator]:first").addClass("indicator-on");
    }

    $("div[id^=marquee]").each(function(){
        $("#indicators").append("<a href='#' id='indicator' class='indicator'></a>");
        $(".indicator:first").addClass("indicator-on");
    });

    $("a[id^=indicator]").click(function(e){
        var index = $("a[id^=indicator]").index(this);
        //alert(index);
        $("div[id=marquee]").hide();
        $("div[id=marquee]").eq(index).show();
        $("a[id=indicator]").removeClass("indicator-on");
        $("a[id=indicator]").eq(index).addClass("indicator-on");
        stopTimer();
        intID = startTimer();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("a[id=indicator], div[id=marquee]").mouseenter(function(){
        stopTimer();
        //alert("mouseenter");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        stopTimer();
        intID = startTimer();
        //alert("mouseexit");
    });

});​
```